# JPA fails when retrieving an Oracle Clob into a Java String

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

Because of the limitations of the `VARCHAR2` type in Oracle, namely, its limit of 4000 bytes in size, I want to use the `CLOB` type for a column in a certain entity. So, after reading the documentation, I declared the field in my JPA entity this way:

```
@Column
@Lob
private String log;
```

I don't have any problems persisting this entity, but when I try to retrieve it with a simple `SELECT m FROM Meeting m`, EclipseLink complains about not being able to convert the type `oracle.sql.CLOB` to `java.lang.String`:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-3001]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException Exception
>   Description: **The object [oracle.sql.CLOB@e9fbb9], of class [class
>   oracle.sql.CLOB], could not be converted to [class java.lang.String]**.
>   Internal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web
>   container has not yet been started

I'm using Eclipselink 2.5.1 as my implementation of JPA. The database is Oracle 10g (10.2.0.3.0) and I'm using ojdbc6.jar as driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you specify the target database platform to use?  See [Specifying the Database for an Application](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/jpa.htm#GSDVG00130) and [Java Persistence API (JPA) Extensions Reference for EclipseLink, Release 2.4](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm) for information.  If it is not set, try setting it to Oracle10.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much Chris. It almost drove me mad!